# pyspark configuration for connecting google cloud platform

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, apache-iceberg

i can't connect to my google cloud platform via pyspark, can anyone help?
i am not using dataproc, just a local spark instance

**background**:
i have downloaded all the jars file into $SPARK_HOME/jars, including

- google-api-client-2.0.0.jar
- google-auth-library-credentials-1.12.1.jar
- google-auth-library-oauth2-http-1.12.1.jar
- google-http-client-1.42.2.jar
- gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.8.jar
- guava-14.0.1.jar
- guava-31.1-jre.jar

i am using the docker image: [jupyter-notebook](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/pyspark-notebook)

**code**:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
builder = SparkSession.builder.appName('GCSFilesRead').config("google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true")\
            .config("google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile","/home/jovyan/work/gcs_admin.json")\
            .config('fs.gs.auth.type','SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_KEYFILE')

spark = builder.getOrCreate()
```

```
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '/home/jovyan/work/gcs_admin.json'
```

```
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
```

```
bucket_name="mybucket"
path=f"gs://{bucket_name}/my_file.csv"

df=spark.read.option("header",True).csv(path, header=True)
df.show()
```

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o59.csv.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/Credential
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2625)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2590)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:537)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue when writing my first pyspark prog.
If you providing key with --files option and  reading in your application, you need to create spark_session first, then use   Sparkfiles to read it,  AND then set conf.
and provide your key along with sparks-submit with

```
--files /path-to-my-gcp-key.json


spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName("s3_to_gs").getOrCreate()
path_to_key = SparkFiles.get("mygcpkey.json")
spark_session.conf.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
spark_session.conf.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", path_to_key)
```